# How to disable fingerprint login timeout

Tags: login, fingerprint-reader

I have fingerprint scanners on a couple of laptops and a desktop via a usb scanner.

Is it possible to disable the timeout at login time, so that it will wait indefinitely for a fingerprint scan?

Comment: What are you currently using for login authentication via fingerprint?

Comment: I'm using fprintd along with the standard ubuntu login screen

Answer (score 8):

Question was posted long time ago, so to whom it may concern (too):

To disable the timeout for **fingerprint-logins** (using fprintd), you've to edit the corresponding configuration file: `/etc/pam.d/common-auth`

open a terminal and enter:

```
sudo gedit /etc/pam.d/common-auth
```

you'll find the following config line:

```
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_fprintd.so max_tries=1 timeout=10 # debug
```

change the `timeout` to **-1** like this (I adjusted `max_tries` too):

```
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_fprintd.so max_tries=2 timeout=-1 # debug
```

perhaps it won't work all the time / in all cases because of other `pam.d` settings - but to figure out that cause, you have to inspect all your **pam.d** configuration.

hth

Comment: According to `man pam_fprintd`, the minimum timeout is 10.

Comment: It turns out that bugs in the source code prevent any values other than 10 through 99 from working.  It only accepts two digits and "-1" does not work.  If you try to put in something higher than 99, you will get the default timeout of 30.  There is a PR to fix this outstanding but it has not been merged.  https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/fprintd/-/merge_requests/195